# What are the advantages of Enhanced for loop and Iterator in Java?

Tags: java, foreach

I would like to know what are the advantages of Enhanced for loop and Iterators in Java +5 ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The strengths and also the weaknesses are pretty well summarized in  Stephen Colebourne (Joda-Time, JSR-310, etc) [Enhanced for each loop iteration control](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000737.html) proposal to extend it in Java 7:

> #### FEATURE SUMMARY:
>
> Extends the Java 5 for-each loop to allow access to the
> loop index,  whether this is the first
> or last iteration, and to remove the
> current item.
>
> #### MAJOR ADVANTAGE
>
> The for-each loop is almost certainly the most new
> popular feature from  Java 5. **It works
> because it increases the abstraction
> level - instead of  having to express
> the low-level details of how to loop
> around a list or  array (with an index
> or iterator), the developer simply
> states that they  want to loop and the
> language takes care of the rest.
> However, all the  benefit is lost as
> soon as the developer needs to access
> the index or to  remove an item**.
>
> The original Java 5 for each work took
> a relatively conservative stance  on a
> number of issues aiming to tackle the
> 80% case. However, loops are  such a
> common form in coding that the
> remaining 20% that was not tackled
> represents a significant body of code.
>
> The process of converting the loop
> back from the for each to be index or
> iterator based is painful. This is
> because **the old loop style** if
> significantly lower-level, **is more
> verbose and less clear**. It is also
> painful as most IDEs don't support
> this kind of 'de-refactoring'.
>
> #### MAJOR BENEFIT:
>
> A common coding idiom is expressed at
> a higher abstraction than at  present.
> This aids **readability and clarity**.
>
> ...

To sum up, the enhanced for loop offers a concise higher level syntax to loop over a list or array which improves clarity and readability. However, it misses some parts: allowing to access the index loop or to remove an item.

#### See also

- [Java 7 - For-each loop control access](http://blog.joda.org/2008/04/java-7-for-each-loop-control-access_1268.html)
- [Stephen Colebourne's original writeup](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18C3rF7OCgUhZjzkuBJzfMzMk6uMY2NNio_SWlEQLzGo/pub)

Comment: That's a nice proposal. Reminds me of [`LoopTagStatus`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) which already exist for ages in JSTL `c:forEach`.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, indeed, I can see the similarities. And I also think that it's a nice proposal. But I didn't check the exact status, not sure it will be included.

Answer (score 12):

For me, it's clear, the main advantage is readability.

```
for(Integer i : list){
   ....
}
```

is clearly better than something like

```
for(int i=0; i < list.size(); ++i){
  ....
}
```

Comment: You need to also add a line doing the extraction of the value. The advantage is that it eliminates a lot of simple boilerplate and any errors therein. After all, there's a great amount of code which just does iteration over collections in one way or another.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's pretty much summed up by the documentation page introducing it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

> Iterating over a collection is uglier than it needs to be

So true..

> The iterator is just clutter. Furthermore, it is an opportunity for error. The iterator variable occurs three times in each loop: that is two chances to get it wrong. The for-each construct gets rid of the clutter and the opportunity for error.

Exactly

> When you see the colon (:) read it as “in.” The loop above reads as “for each TimerTask t in c.” As you can see, the for-each construct combines beautifully with generics. It preserves all of the type safety, while removing the remaining clutter. Because you don't have to declare the iterator, you don't have to provide a generic declaration for it. (The compiler does this for you behind your back, but you need not concern yourself with it.)

I'd like to sum it up more, but I think that page does it pretty much perfectly.

Comment: The link is dead now - any chance you could update it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Major drawback is the creation of an Iterator, which is not there with an index-based loop.
It is usually OK, but in performance-critical sections (in a real-time application for instance, when it has to run several hundreds times a second), it can cause major GC intervention...

Comment: This answer right here is worth MILLIONS OF DOLLARS if you think about the implications!  Restating:  when you use a for-in loop, Java implicitly constructs an Iterator object that is used for iterating over the iterable.  This means that if you use for-in in a busy part of your code, you're going to wind up with a LOT garbage in your heap to collect from all these phantom Iterators that get created and you'll take a tremendous performance hit.  High AbstractList$Itr object counts appear in profilers.  Don't use for-in loops in performance-sensitive code, use a for-index loop!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over any collection that's Iterable and also arrays.
And the performance difference isn't anything you should be worried about at all.

**Readability** is important.

```
Prefer this    
for (String s : listofStrings) 
    {
     ... 
    }

over

    for (Iterator<String> iter = listofStrings.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
    {
     String s = iter.next();
     ...
    }
```

Note that if you need to delete elements as you iterate, you need to use `Iterator`.

For example,

```
List<String> list = getMyListofStrings(); 

    for (Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) 
    {
        String s = iter.next();
        if (someCondition) {
            iter.remove(); 
        }
    }
```

You can't use `for(String s : myList)` to delete an element in the list.
Also note that when iterating through an array, foreach (or enhanced for) can be used only to obtain the elements, you can't modify the elements in the array.
For more info, see [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner syntax !
There is no difference from the performance perspective as this is just a convenience for a programmer.

Comment: In fact, the enhanced for loop might be slower little a bit in many cases. But it is ignorable.

Comment: Ohh I didnt know that. Just curious in what case .. any pointers/references?

Comment: It was my understanding (but I could be wrong) that the enhanced for loop compiled to the same byte code as the regular for loop.  If that is correct, then run-time behaviour should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the enhanced for loop provides cleaner syntax, readable code and less type.

Plus, it avoids the possible 'index out of bound' error scenario too. For example, when you iterate a list manually, you might use the index variable in a wrong way, like:

```
for(int i=0; i<= list.size(); i++)
```

which will throw exception. But incase of enhanced for loop, we are leaving the iterating task to the compiler. It completely avoids the error case.

Answer (score 0):

As others already answer, it is a syntax sugar for cleaner. If you compare to the class Iterator loop, you will found one less variable you will have to declare.

Answer (score 0):

It is more concise. Only problem is null checking.

```
for (String str : strs) {  // make sure strs is not null here
    // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: It's certainly not necessarily a problem: I can have a list or array of objects that has nulls at some indices, and I'd hate to be unable to iterate over them. If I don't like a null, I can do this too: `if (str==null) continue;`

Answer (score 0):

A foreach/enhanced for/for loop serves to provide a cursor onto a data object. This is particularly useful when you think in terms of “walk a file line by line” or “walk a result set record by record” as it is simple and straightforward to implement.

This also provides a more general and improved way of iterating compared to index-based methods because there is no longer any need for the caller (for loop) to know how values are fetched or collection sizes or other implementation details.

Answer (score -2):

Less typing!  Plus more help from the compiler

Answer (score -3):

The enhanced for-loop offers the following main advantage:

```
for (int i=0; i <= list.size(); i++)
```

It eliminates the repeated calculation of `list.size()` on every iteration in the non-enhanced version above.  This is a performance advantage that matters.

Alternatively, you may calculate the size outside the loop as follows using an additional variable:

```
int size = list.size();
for (int i=0; i <= size; i++)
```

Comment: The compiler will surely do that for you anyway, there is no advantage in making the code less readable.

Comment: Bo, I am advocating the use of enhanced for loop.  Are you saying that the old style is more readable?

Comment: No, I'm saying that moving `list.size()` outside the loop makes the code less readable without improving performance.

Comment: That is why I am saying to use for(Type type: list) instead of for(int i=0; i<= list.size(); i++) or int size = list.size(); for(int i=0; i<= size; i++)

Comment: I prefer for(int i = 0, ii = list.size(); i < ii; i++)