# Convert 1 string element to integer

Tags: java

Write a program which checks an array of String contains valid numbers.If the string contains ".", convert it to Double, otherwise convert it to an Integer.Input should be array of string { "10.20", "123456", "12.invalid"}.

My problem is that 123456 is getting changed to double.I have to change it to int.Please help :(

```
public class Ch7LU3Ex1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] str = new String []{"10.20","123456","12.invalid"};
        int i,count=0;
        try
        {
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                int l = str[i].length();
                for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
                {
                    if(str[i].charAt(j)=='.')
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if(count!=0)
                {
                    double d = Double.parseDouble(str[i]);
                    System.out.println(d);
                }
                else
                {
                    int e = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: @DOK: [The homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: @DOK: nope, the homework tag is not to be used in general. Check out the meta site for details.

Comment: Its not my homework.It is a part of some JAVA studying course I am doing :)

Comment: I recommend using regular expressions for your use case. http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: @sorencito Regex is a little overkill for this. :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Robin. You did a good job on your own working your way through this problem. Now, you can see from some more experienced folks how to create a more elegant solution. By struggling with it on your own, you will probably understand the other solutions better.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(str[i].indexOf('.') == -1) {
    int e = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
}
else {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str[i]);
}
```

This is much more elegant than all of your unneeded loops.  Good luck!

To understand how this works, [see the String API for indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)).

Answer (score 2):

As for the current way you are using, you need to reset the `count` to `0` in each iteration, else each of your values after first double value is found will be converted to double, since your `count` value is `non-zero` in every case.

So, in your first for loop, you need to reset the count at the start as follows: -

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    count = 0;
```

Now, you are really making your task complex. You don't need to use the `count` variable at all. Also, you don't need the `nested loop` there. You can do it simple one loop like this. Just don't work on individual characters on your own. Java library has methods which have already done it for you. Use them instead: -

```
for (String str: arr) {
    if (str.contains(".")) {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } else {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}
```

The loop is used is called [enhanced for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328672/what-are-the-advantages-of-enhanced-for-loop-and-iterator-in-java).

[`String#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method checks whether a string contains a certain character or not. Or, you can use [`String#indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) method to find the index of `.` in your string. And if it returns a positive value, then your string contains that character.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a loop at all. I would assume you don't have random data and you know the type of each "column" should be.

```
String[] str = {"10.20", "123456", "12.invalid"};

double d = Double.parseDouble(str[0]);
int i = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
String s = str[2];
```

If you don't know if a value should be a `double` or an `int`, you can always parse it as a double without loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to set count back to zero for each string and you are not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

After one iteration set again count to zero `count=0` , in your second iteration count is not zero hence again consider as a double value

Comment: You are welcome, But you could do it easily without having two for loops. Check other answers also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset your count variable to 0 after every examined element. This way count is incremented since "10.20" includes a dot and is not reset for "123456".

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mess, but the point is that you don't reset your count for each member of the `str`.

So if you add a `counter=0;` in the loop that goes trough all the characters of one string, you'd probably get what you want?

some extra tips:

- use readable variable names
- indent your code

Comment: Yeah I am always messy with variable names and my code was indented but I changed it all to put on this website.