# weird java Iterator items being replaced

Tags: java, object, iterator

So, In my code I get a list of components, iterate the components, inside every component I get the component's maintenances and iterate over them. The problem is, the items are beying replaced and are not re-created, as I wish:

```
List<ComponentRelation> componentRelations = getComponentRelations();

List<MaintenanceRequired> allMaintenancesRequired = new ArrayList<MaintenanceRequired>();

for (Iterator<ComponentRelation> iterator = componentRelations.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    ComponentRelation componentRelation = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Getting maintenances from "+componentRelation.getComponent().getName()+" at position "+ComponentInstallationPosition.getPositionString(componentRelation.getInstallationPosition()));
    for (Iterator<MaintenanceRequired> iterator2 = maintenancesDAO.getRequiredMaintenancesByComponentRelation(componentRelation).iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {
        MaintenanceRequired maintenanceRequired = (MaintenanceRequired) iterator2.next();
        maintenanceRequired.setMaintenancePerformedOnComponent(omponentRelation);
            allMaintenancesRequired.add(maintenanceRequired);
    }
}
```

So, the println is correct, but inside the item:

```
public void setMaintenancePerformedOnComponent(ComponentRelation maintenancePerformedOnComponent) {
    if (this.maintenancePerformedOnComponent!=null)
        System.out.println("SETTING "+ComponentInstallationPosition.getPositionString(this.maintenancePerformedOnComponent.getInstallationPosition())+" to "+ComponentInstallationPosition.getPositionString(maintenancePerformedOnComponent.getInstallationPosition()));
    else System.out.println("SETTING "+ComponentInstallationPosition.getPositionString(maintenancePerformedOnComponent.getInstallationPosition()));
    this.maintenancePerformedOnComponent = maintenancePerformedOnComponent;
}
```

So the print says:

```
"getting maintenances from X-1, position 1"
"SETTING 1"
"SETTING 1"
"SETTING 1"
"SETTING 1"
"SETTING 1"
"getting maintenances from X-2, position 2"
"SETTING 1 to 2"
"SETTING 1 to 2"
"SETTING 1 to 2"
"SETTING 1 to 2"
"SETTING 1 to 2"
```

So, why would he sets 1 to 2 if it's another object??

As John asked for, what I do it:

```
create empty list of items Y;

get list of items X;

iterator of list of items X {
    get from database all Y inside X and iterate{
        set iterated Y that he has a position K;
        put iterated Y inside created initially empty list of Y; // first line
    }
}
```

Comment: static class variables?

Comment: It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd come up with a short but complete example demonstrating the problem - ideally one which didn't have quite such long-winded and clearly business-specific names.

Comment: Not static.. adding simpler example down now

Comment: added a "brief" of what I am doing, does anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: @VitorMendes unfortunately your "simpler example" doesn't help much; editing the question to use class & variable names will make it easier to read through (as would using [enhanced for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328672/what-are-the-advantages-of-enhanced-for-loop-and-iterator-in-java)). That said, I think @turbo is right; the behavior you're seeing would happen if `this.maintenancePerformedOnComponent` is `static`.

Comment: Well, thanks but not static.. I am checking if it is Hibernate related and will post what I find.

Comment: I don’t get your question. Your method has a big `if` statement yielding to different behavior depending on an instance variable and you are asking “So, why would …[it expose different behavior]… if it's another object”? Of course, because that’s the point of OOP, different objects may behave differently. Your method starts with `if (this.maintenancePerformedOnComponent!=null)` and obviously for one object it is `null` for the other it isn’t.

Comment: "if (this.maintenancePerformedOnComponent!=null)" is just to show me that it is really replacing the value for different objects. The first object is null, so it tells me just "SETTING 1". The other was supposed to be null, cause it is a different one and not a static variable, but it is not, and replaces the last one.

Answer (score 0):

take a closer look at:

```
System.out.println("SETTING "+ComponentInstallationPosition.getPositionString(this.maintenancePerformedOnComponent.getInstallationPosition())+" to "+ComponentInstallationPosition.getPositionString(maintenancePerformedOnComponent.getInstallationPosition()));
```

you referencing not to local `maintenancePerformedOnComponent` but to `this.maintenancePerformedOnComponent`

Comment: Yes, as explained, that is inside the Object, the setter. Thanks for the reply, any other ideas?