# What is the difference between two approaches to iterate a HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I know it might be a simple question, but I don't wish to miss any small but important point.

Please explain what is the difference between the approaches to traverse a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> asd1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
asd1.put(1,11);
asd1.put(2,22);
asd1.put(3,33);

// approach 1
for(int i:asd1.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(i+" : "+asd1.get(i));
}

// approach 2

Iterator it = asd1.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " : " + pairs.getValue());
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

Comment: First approach is just user friendly without much implementation details.Both used iterator for this.

Comment: A Key Set it also Iterable (by means of Set) which means it can also generate an Iterable. It would be better to compare the "different ways" to iterate an Iterator: with the *enchanted for-loop* or with a more manual hasNext loop. By mixing a Key Set/Entry Set the issue is merely compounded and focus is lost..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328672/what-are-the-advantages-of-enhanced-for-loop-and-iterator-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference I know about is.

According to [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

> **ForEach Loop** Vs **Iterator**
>
> The program *needs access to the iterator* in order to **remove** the
>   current element.The for-each loop hides the iterator, so you cannot
>   call remove. Therefore, the for-each loop is not usable for filtering.

So The for-each loop hides the iterator so internally foreach also uses Iterator but as it is hidden you can't take all advantages of Iterator in foreach.

---

There are certain limitations of enhanced for loop one of the limitation I want to put here is.

- It is possible to iterate only *forward* by single steps.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' Glad to help you But _I am not Sir!! :)_

Comment: without 'Sir' , comment was small in size was not being posted :) :) :)

Comment: Ha ha...Next time replace Sir With Friend/Met. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is performing a hash lookup at each `asd1.get(i)`. The second approach is iterating the key/value pairs without needing to do the lookup.  So the second approach will be faster and thus preferred.

I'm not sure why you are removing in one and not the other?

Answer (score 1):

The second approach allows to remove elements, the first approach is shorter.