# Using ArrayList instead of an array to avoid using a normal for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm reviewing a piece of code that looks like this:

> ```
> public WrappedItem[] processItems(Item[] items)
> {
>     List<WrappedItem> wrappedItems = new ArrayList<>();   
>     for (Item item : items)
>     {
>         /* …do something with the item… */
>         wrappedItems.add(WrappedItem.wrap(item));
>     }
>     return wrappedItems.toArray(new WrappedItem[0]);
> }
> ```

A list is created so that the enhanced for loop can be used and then it is converted to an array to be returned.

Would this be better from a performance and code style perspective?

```
public WrappedItem[] processItems(Item[] items)
{
    WrappedItem[] wrappedItems = WrappedItem[items.length];   
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        Item item = items[i]
        /* …do something with the item… */
        wrappedItems[i] = WrappedItem.wrap(item);
    }
    return wrappedItems;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you fail to realize that the enhanced for loop works just fine on arrays too.

Comment: Nope, he did notice, but I am more concerned that this is example code (since `item` is not wrapped when put in `wrappedItems`). This is for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why is this migrated **from** code review?

Comment: Because code review deals with real code, that works, and this code, does not.

Comment: @bowmore No I noticed. But the author preferred the enhanced for loop.

Comment: Without doubt, the second solution will be faster.... creates just one array instead of an ArrayList, which has an internal array, and the toArray which creates a second.

Comment: Well, if you really need to return an array, then create an array directly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this has anything to do with the type of loop.  You could always keep your own index value in the first loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you cannot simply directly construct an array *and* make use of the advanced for loop :

```
public WrappedItem[] processItems(Item[] items)
{
    WrappedItem[] wrappedItems = WrappedItem[items.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (Item item : items)
    {
        /* …do something with the item… */
        wrappedItems[i++] = item;
    }
    return wrappedItems;
}
```

Comment: Same answer, same time, I'll drop mine.

Answer (score 0):

From code style perspective using enhanced loop increases readability, as it's more abstract than "standard" for loop.

Standard for increases control, but introduces also a space for possible errors, as you're manipulating the indices and lengths, which everybody is familiar with, but still it's exposing some of the internal data's structure which is somehow against encapsulation...

Have a look also at this post [What are the Advantages of Enhanced for loop and Iterator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328672/what-are-the-advantages-of-enhanced-for-loop-and-iterator-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As your code is written in the question you are not wrapping the item (despite the name) but just putting into a differently type array. This can be done even easier:

```
public WrappedItem[] processItems(Item[] items)
{
  WrappedItem[] wrappedItems
    = Arrays.copyOf(items, items.length, WrappedItem[].class);
  for (Item item : items)
  {
    /* …do something with the item… */
  }
  return wrappedItems;
}
```

If you need Java 5 compatibility you can use

```
WrappedItem[] wrappedItems = Arrays.asList(items).toArray(new WrappedItem[0]);
```

instead of `Arrays.copyOf`.

---

Now that you have updated your question it’s clear that it’s not that easy. Then the answer is that the `List` based version creates some overhead but in most practical scenarios it will be negligible. As pointed out by others you can also combine a for-each loop with an additional index variable but to me it doesn’t look convincing as the index variable has the wrong scope (you have to declare it outside the loop) and it’s not really simpler than the traditional for loop.

Maybe the final words come from the Java 8 solution:

```
public WrappedItem[] processItems(Item[] items) {
  return Arrays.stream(items)
      .map(item -> {
          /* …do something with the item… */
          return WrappedItem.wrap(item);
      }).toArray(WrappedItem[]::new);
}
```

or

```
public WrappedItem[] processItems(Item[] items) {
  return Arrays.stream(items)
      .peek(item -> {
          /* …do something with the item… */
      }).map(WrappedItem::wrap).toArray(WrappedItem[]::new);
}
```