# Merging the first Element in an array with another array and pairing them merge them to a single array

Tags: java, arrays

Enquiry on how can one match the element in first array be paired to the first element in Second array?
e.g {"jane","doe"} being in First array and {45,24} hence pairing output to be jane:45
doe:24

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, array1.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> array1[i], i -> array2[i]));`

Comment: Possibly related: [Can I iterate over two arrays at once by Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26966213)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have 2 arrays ara1 and ara2 that you want to merge into an array outAra. This loops to the length of whichever array is smaller, copying the con-catted  value of ara1 and ara2 into outAra. Is this what you were asking for?

```
int[] ara1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
char[] ara2 = new char[]{'a','b','c','d','e'};

int len = ara1.length < ara2.length? ara1.length:ara2.length;
String[] outAra = new String[len];
for(int i = 0; i < ara1.length && i < ara2.length; i++)
    outAra[i] = String.valueOf(ara1[i]) + ara2[i];
```